# アクセストークン取得の為のOAuth認証が上手くいきません

Tags: php, api, oauth, instagram

ローカル環境で、Instagram のAPIを使ってPHP開発を行っています。アクセストークン取得の為のアプリの認証の際、ログイン画面から、InstagramにURLを飛ばすと下記のようなエラー表示がでてしまいます。
認証画面が立ち上がるはずなのですが、間違っている該当箇所について検討がつかず、エラー解決の為の参考文献も見つけられない状態です。
どなたかアドバイスいただけますでしょうか。宜しくお願いします。

エラー：

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "error_type": "OAuthException",
    "error_message": "You must include a valid client_id, response_type, and redirect_uri parameters"
}
```

ブラウザで返ってくるURL：

https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]redirect_uri=http://insta.com/htdocs/redirect.php&%26scope=basic%2Bcomments%2Brelationships%2Blikes&%26response_type=code

```
session_start();
if (empty($_GET['code'])) {
  // 認証前の準備
  $params = array(
  'client_id' => CLIENT_ID,
  '&redirect_uri' => SITE_URL.'htdocs/redirect.php',
  '&scope' => 'basic+comments+relationships+likes',
  '&response_type' => 'code'
  );
  $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?'.http_build_query($params);

  // Instagram にとばす
  header('Location: '.$url);
  exit;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22308895/instagram-client-side-authentication-issue は試されましたか？

Answer (score 1):

下記で如何でしょうか？

```
 // 認証前の準備
 $params = array(
     'client_id' => CLIENT_ID,
     'redirect_uri' => urlencode(SITE_URL.'htdocs/redirect.php'),
     'scope' => 'basic comments relationships likes',
     'response_type' => 'code'
 );
 $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?'.http_build_query($params);

 // Instagram にとばす
 header('Location: '.$url);
 exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

http_build_queryに渡しているarrayは、&や+を使わなくても確か自動で付加されたと思います。